# The convergence of $\int_0^{\infty} \sin(x)(x-[x])/x^{\alpha}$

Tags: integration, inequality, convergence-divergence, ceiling-and-floor-functions, holder-inequality

I need to evaluate the following integral

$$\int_0^{\infty} \sin(x)(x-[x])/x^{\alpha}dx$$
where $\alpha\in (0,1)$ and $[x]$ is the floor function.
Without $x-[x]$, we can evaluate the integral easily using analytical continuation.
$$\int_0^{\infty} \sin(x)/x^{\alpha}dx=\Im \int_0^{\infty} e^{ix}/x^{\alpha}dx=\Im [\Gamma(1+\alpha)/i^{\alpha-1}]$$

In the presence of $x-[x]$, my idea is that one could use inequality to upper bound the integral if it converges or lower bound the integral if it diverges. But I'm not sure what kind of inequality I should use.

I tried Hölder's inequality, but it will square the sin function in the upper bound, which makes it diverge.

Comment: You have checked that the integral converges, I guess.

Comment: $x-\lfloor x\rfloor=\text{frac}(x)$, the fractional part of $x$

Comment: The Fourier series of $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ gives $\sin(x)(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)=\frac{\sin(x)}2-\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{\cos((2\pi n-1)x)-\cos((2\pi n+1)x)}{2\pi n}$, integrating termwise gives a Dirichlet series

Comment: @reuns Integrating this series termwise can be justified? I don't think it's  absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 2):

Let's settle (as in the *title* of the OP) just the *convergence* of the integral. The obvious choice is Dirichlet's test: we only have to show that $\int^N_0\sin(x)(x-[x])\,dx$ is uniformly bounded. Since $\sin(x)(x-[x])$ is bounded, it's sufficient to show that for integer $N$. But then,
$$\int^N_0\sin(x)(x-[x])\,dx=\sum^{N-1}_{n=0}\int^{n+1}_n\sin(x)(x-[x])\,dx=\int^1_0y\,\sum^{N-1}_{n=0}\sin(n+y)\,dy,$$ and
$$\sum^{N-1}_{n=0}\sin(n+y)=\cos y\,\sum^{N-1}_{n=0}\sin n+\sin y\,\sum^{N-1}_{n=0}\cos n.$$
Since $$\left|\sum^{N-1}_{n=0}\sin n\right|=\left|\frac{\cos(1/2)-\cos(N-1/2)}{2\,\sin(1/2)}\right|\le\frac1{\sin(1/2)}$$ and $$\left|\sum^{N-1}_{n=0}\cos n\right|=\left|\frac{\sin(N-1/2)+\sin(1/2)}{2\,\sin(1/2)}\right|\le\frac1{\sin(1/2)},$$ this *is* uniformly bounded. $x^{-\alpha}\to0$ as $x\to\infty$ guarantees the convergence of the integral.

BONUS: If $\alpha>0$, $e^{-bx}\,x^{-\alpha}\to0$ as $x\to\infty$ uniformly in $b\ge0$, so $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty} e^{-bx}\,\sin(x)(x-[x])\,x^{-\alpha}\,dx$ converges uniformly in $b\ge0$.

Answer (score 0):

To answer to @ProfessorVector

For $a\in (1,2)$, $$\int_0^{\infty} \sin(x)(x-[x])x^{-a}dx= \lim_{b\to 0} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-bx}\sin(x)(x-[x])x^{-a}dx$$ $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-bx}\sin(x)(x-[x])x^{-a}dx$ is analytic for $a < 2$.

For $a \in (0,1/2)$

- $e^{-bx/2}(\frac{\sin(x)}2-\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{\cos((2\pi n-1)x)-\cos((2\pi n+1)x)}{2\pi n})$  converges in $L^2(0,\infty)$
- and $x^{-a}e^{-bx/2}$ is $L^2(0,\infty)$

Thus no problem to switch $\int,\sum$
$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-bx}\sin(x)(x-[x])x^{-a}dx$$ $$= \int_0^{\infty} e^{-bx}(\frac{\sin(x)}2-\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{\cos((2\pi n-1)x)-\cos((2\pi n+1)x)}{2\pi n})x^{-a}dx$$
$$ = \Gamma(1-a)\Re(\frac{(b+i)^{a-1}}{2i}-\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(b+i(2\pi n-1))^{a-1}-( b+i(2\pi n+1))^{a-1}}{2\pi n})$$

The latter series extends analytically to $\Re(a)\in (0,2)$  so it must stay equal to $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-bx}\sin(x)(x-[x])x^{-a}dx$.

Thus for $a\in (1,2)$ we can let $b\to 0$ to obtain

$$\int_0^{\infty} \sin(x)(x-[x])x^{-a}dx = \Gamma(1-a)\Re(\frac{i^{a-1}}{2i}-\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(i(2\pi n-1))^{a-1}-(i(2\pi n+1))^{a-1}}{2\pi n})$$

Comment: $\int^\infty_0e^{-bx}\sin x\,dx=\frac1{1+b^2}$, now letting $b\to 0$ gives...?

Comment: I don't see what you mean.

Comment: You do, thus the edit. $b\to0$ is justified for $a\in(1,2)$, but the OP has $\alpha\in(0,1)$.

Comment: No I don't. I thought it was $(1,2)$. I think my answer proves it converges for $(0,1)$  but it is not fully obvious.

Comment: It converges just fine, and with the additional factor $e^{-bx}$, even uniformly in $b$, but that needs another line or two.

Comment: I don't understand anything of your comments.

Comment: The convergence of $\int_1^{\infty} \sin(x)(x-[x])x^{-a}dx$ for $a\in (0,1)$ follows from integrating by parts and that we know the Fourier pseudo-series of the primitive of $\sin(x)(x-[x])$ which converges absolutely so is bounded.

Comment: Pseudo-series or series, can you integrate it, termwise? Yet another round of that circle doesn't prove anything. The primitive of $\sin(x)(x-[x])$ is uniformly bounded, that's what counts.

Comment: Is it obvious that the primitive of $\sin(x)(x-[x])$ is bounded ? It becomes obvious once we know its Fourier transform is a sum of Dirac $\sum_j r_j \delta(\xi-u_j)$ with $\sum_j |r_j|<\infty$ (if you don't like Fourier transforms in the sense of distribution you can use that the series for $\sin(x)(x-[x])$ converges in $L^2_{loc}$ so yes we can integrate it termwise)